# Verifying if obect exists from a text file

Tags: java

I'm writing a method that takes books in a csv file and convert it into a list of document. To avoid having duplicates, my method is verifying that the document I want to add isn't already in the list. I'm doing it like so :

```
while(line!= null) {
    String[] attributes = line.split(",");
    Document doc = createDocFromCsv(attributes);
    boolean verify = false;
    Iterator<Document> i = documents.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext() && (verify == false) ) {
        Document a = i.next();
        if (!a.equals(doc)) {
            System.out.println(" Wasn't found in the list" + doc); 
        } else {
            System.out.println(" Was found in the list" + doc);
            verify = true;
        }
        if (verify == false) documents.add(doc);
    }   
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

### So that's the logic :

I create a document based on the line i'm reading in the CSV file

-I then, compare it to the documents in my list that where previously added from the CSV file

-If it already exists, i read the next line of the CSV file

-Else, I add it to the library

The verifying loop works well, it detects which book is or isn't in the list. 
The problem occurs when I call add(doc e ) insite my verifying loop. But If I Do it outside, i'm adding every books and therefore i'm getting duplicates.

Could you help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is your data structure but there is java collection that would do what you want and it is called a **Set**. So instead of adding the documents to the list add them to a **Set** and what you want to achieve will happen automagically :)

If you still wanna keep using list then the problem with your code is that you try to add the document inside the while loop - while still iterating on the list. You need to add it AFTER the loop has finished (and you have checked all documents)

```
 Iterator<Document> i = documents.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext() && (verify == false) ) {
            Document a = i.next();
            if (!a.equals(doc)) {
                 System.out.println(" Wasn't found in the list" + doc);

            } else {
                System.out.println(" Was found in the list" + doc);
                verify = true;


            }

        }   
if (verify == false) documents.add(doc);
```

And you will get lots of "Wasn't found in the list " prints ;) because you do it for each element of the collection

Comment: My project asks for this part to be working through written methods, I can't really use java collections. Oh thanks for the clarifications, it was normal for the prints, I was checking if eveyrthing goes through well, I'm trying your solution right now.

Comment: well you are still using a collection - the list ;)

Comment: Ok thanks for the fast and quick answer, that's what I needed. It's a shame it took me so much time and help for such a simple solution. Thanks a lot and have a good day.

Comment: you too ;) you can always accept my answer in return. Everybody wants the points ;)

Comment: Was doing it right now, there is a 4 minutes delay, you are too fast haha

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused why you're not allowed to add your objects to a Set but you can add them to a List.  Either way, all collections implement a .contains(newDocument).  So define hashCode and equals in your Document class, and just check to see if the collection contains the new document.

Basically, what you're attempting to do is rewrite an already optimized solution that exists in all collections.